# how to read int,double,and sentence of string using same scanner variable

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            String s=new String();
            int x=sc.nextInt();
            double y=sc.nextDouble();
            s = sc.next();

            System.out.println("String:"+s);
            System.out.println("Double: "+y); 
            System.out.println("Int: "+x);     
     }       
}
```

it scans only one word pleasd give any suggestions...

Comment: `hasNextInt`,`hasNextDouble()` explore these methods.

Comment: @keppil is it really duplicate ?

Comment: @FastSnail and keppil I dont think its a dupe OP is not using `nextLine()` anywhere

Comment: @singhakash it's not duplicate .but it was unclear for me

Comment: `next()` only reads one word, this is it's purpose. If you want to read a whole line use `nextLine();`

Comment: @singhakash vote to reopen

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you reopen the question as it is not a dupe of the given thread?

Comment: @Fastsnail: I figured it was close enough, and had an accepted answer that explained and resolved the situation here as well. Good thing you got it reopened since multiple people didn't agree with me though.

Answer (score 26):

You can try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();

    scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```

Because the Scanner object will read the rest of the line where its previous read left off.

If there is nothing on the line, it simply consumes the newline and moves to the starting of the next line.

After double declaration, you have to write: `scan.nextLine();`

Answer (score 8):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        double y = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();
        String s = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + y);
        System.out.println("Int: " + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
s = sc.next();
```

> it scans only one word pleasd give any suggestions...

This is what `next();` is intended to do.  If you want to read multiple words, the simplest solution is to read a line of text. e.g.

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

If you need to read multi-line text, you need to workout a strategy for doing this such as reading everything in a loop until you have a blank line.

Note: while the answer is similar to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) the difference is that you don't *discard* the rest of the line, but rather you use the String returned by `nextLine();`

If you are expecting the input to be

```
 1 2.0 Hello World
```

then you want to use the suggestion above, however if the input is on multiple lines like this

```
 1 2.0
 Hello World
```

You will need to discard the rest of the line with an extra class to `nextLine()` as the link above suggests.

Comment: Well, since you're one of those who removed the dupe note of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods), you could add a note to your answer to avoid a following question with exactly this problem :). If the uses `nextLine` instead, then his input will be skipped.

Comment: @Tom Thank you, I have added a comment as to why it is similar but not a dup.

Comment: That's not what I meant :P. It is currently not a dupe, correct, but since you suggest to use `nextLine` instead of `next` to read the whole line, he will run into the same problem asked in that question. His new `nextLine` call will read the rest of the line, that was left behind of the prior `nextDouble()` call. With "the note you could write" I meant that you can lead him to that question to get this problem solved when he runs into it.

Comment: @Tom You could be right, it's not clear from the OP's question whether the String is on the same line as I assumed or on a different line.

Comment: Right, this could be true ... never thought about an input like "1 1.0 test blub test" (on the same line).

Comment: @Tom worth adding a note about each possibility. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you skip as follows

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest to try out this block of code

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

I hope this would not skip reading the String input (or just read a single word skipping rest of the Line) after a double or integer input..

follow me on fb/ayur.sharma

Answer (score 0):

If you use the nextLine() method immediately following the nextInt() method, recall that nextInt() reads integer tokens; because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer input is still queued in the input buffer and the next nextLine() will be reading the remainder of the integer line (which is empty).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
     double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
     String s = scan.nextLine();

     System.out.println("String: " + s);
     System.out.println("Double: " + d);
     System.out.println("Int: "+ i);
     }
}
```

Comment: Take input - int, double and sentence.
print the same as output

Comment: This doesn't work for all valid reasons! You have to check Arun's answer for the working solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
     double d = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
     scan.nextLine();
     String s = scan.nextLine();
     scan.close();

     System.out.println("String: " + s);
     System.out.println("Double: " + d);
     System.out.println("Int: "+ i);
     }
}
```

When switching between reading tokens of input and reading a full line of input, you need to make another call to nextLine() because the Scanner object will read the rest of the line where its previous read left off.

If there is nothing on the line, it simply consumes the newline and moves to the beginning of the next line.

After double declaration, you have to write: scan.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your answer**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {     
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = scan.nextInt();         
    double d = scan.nextDouble(); 

    scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();  

    //if you want to skip the unnecessary input
    //scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    System.out.println("String: " + s);       
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);      
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);

   scan.close();
}
```